# Samba use Active Directory users

Tags: server, samba, configuration, active-directory

I inherited an ubuntu 8.10 server that is currently running as a samba server and apache web server.
I would like to make a new server with ubuntu 19.10 and copy the existing configurations on that one.
I usually start from scratch and I never configured samba to integrate with active directory.
Will this config in smb.conf be enough?

```
# Global parameters
[global]
        workgroup = domain
        realm = domain.com
        server string = %h NEWSAMBASERVER (Samba %v)
        security = ADS
        password server = domaincontroller.domain.com
        #security = DOMAIN
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\sUNIX\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\sUNIX\spassword:* %n\n .
        username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
        syslog = 0
        max log size = 1000
        name resolve order = wins host bcast
        socket options = IPTOS_LOWDELAY TCP_NODELAY SO_SNDBUF=4096 SO_RCVBUF=4096
        load printers = No
        preferred master = No
        local master = No
        domain master = No
        wins support = Yes
        invalid users = root
        hosts allow = 10.100., 127.
#       printing = lprng
#       lppause command = lpc hold '%p' %j
#       lpresume command = lpc release '%p' %j
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ubuntu 8 is very old, I feel starting from scratch would be the better option.

[Does this guide help?](https://www.howtoforge.com/samba_active_directory)

Comment: it's just the first result from google. is there a guide for ubuntu?

Comment: @Malkavian It is the top result because Samba isn't limited to just Ubuntu and because guides cited in many places tend to float to the top. The official Ubuntu resources are here [1](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-ad-integration.html) [2](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html)

Comment: i'm using this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/sssd-ad.html and this guide https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/samba-ad-integration.html and this guide https://www.howtoforge.com/samba_active_directory i will eventually make it.

Comment: @Malkavian - Please reply with your successful method / guide as an answer to your own question, when you succeed.